# Node js express can't parse body after routes moved into own folder

Tags: json, node.js, express

Moved routes into their own folder now I cant parse the response body. Controller sends body correctly. App worked correctly when routes were in server js file.

Server.js BEFORE

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');

app.use('/',routes);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(__dirname + '/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist'));
app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/public/bower_components/jquery/dist'));
app.use('/angular', express.static(__dirname + '/public/bower_components/angular'));
app.use('/controllers', express.static(__dirname + '/public/controllers'));
```

Routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ObjectId = require('mongojs').ObjectID;
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlist',['contactlist'])
var router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.put('/contactlist/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log("req.body.name");//gives undefined
    db.contactlist.findAndModify({
        query:{_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)},
        update:{ $set:{name:req.body.name,email:req.body.email,number:req.body.number}},
        new: true}, 
        function(err,doc){
            res.json(doc);
        });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Also, any thoughts as to why I have to append routes.js here instead of just / routes?

```
var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');
```

Folder Structure

```
-App
    node_mods/
    public/
        index.html
        controllers/
        resources/
    routes/
        routes.js
```

Server.js AFTER

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));

var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');

app.use('/',routes);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //look for static files js html css etc
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(__dirname + '/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist'));
app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/public/bower_components/jquery/dist'));
app.use('/angular', express.static(__dirname + '/public/bower_components/angular'));
app.use('/controllers', express.static(__dirname + '/public/controllers'));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('server running on port 3000');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body is parsing after your route is called.

Pass your `body-parser` code in your main server file generally, it is `server.js` before all the routes.

Like this:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
```

Comment: I try it in the server.js file as you request and still receive the same error.

Comment: the same error as before, can not read property 'name' of undefined.

Comment: can you show me your server.js file with updated code?

Comment: I added it to the main post

Comment: are you sending form data?

Comment: try to use `extended: true` in body-parser

Comment: yes using angular model, everything worked perfectly until I moved the routes. Data was parsed etc..

Comment: change your extended:true instead of false

Comment: Whoops, I lied, changing to true fixed my issue. I didn't restart server after I made the change

Answer (score 1):

As for your (second?) quetion , about importing requiring routes.js:

When you do

```
var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');
```

you're not calling the routes. You're, in fact requiring a module. That is not only routes data, but also the router object Behaviour, including associated middleware for some of all of the routes.

If you look carefully, your router.js exports the router "object" ( or function, call it as you want). So when you require it, you get the whole package, not only data